# How to write a business logic involving two models in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am confused and dont know how to write the business logic in django and django rest framework.

How to validate the student that does not already exist in the registration (registration_no will be provided through front end and it will be included in the json) table at the time of student creation?

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    sex  = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES,max_length=255, null=True)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

RegisrationModel

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    registration_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, 
    on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='registrations')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.registration_no
```

Comment: you want to check if a user is already created or not at the time of registration ?

Comment: i want to check whether student name with the same registration number is already existed at the time of student creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `save()` method of model **Registration** in order to make your verification and raise an exception if there is an student with the same name and registration number already in the database.

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    registration_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, 
    on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='registrations')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.registration_no

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            Registration.objects.get(student__name=self.name, registration_no=self.registration_no)
        except:
            super(Registration, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise Exception("Student already registered")
```

Comment: i want to pass (name, registration_no) from the front end. so checking will be by using these two parameters

Comment: Sorry, but I think my answer already checks those parameters.

Comment: can you please upload complete implementation

Comment: I can not upload a complete implementation because I don't know the front end implementation you are using, but I am pretty sure that, whatever it is, you are sending a **POST** request from the front end to the back end, so the back end must catch such request through a Django **view** and perform the creation attempt. Something like `registration = Registration.objects.create(registration_no=registration_no, student=student)`. This is enough to trigger the save validation.